# Server might be compromised?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, security, server

I wasn't really sure were I would be able to get help for this so i am hoping someone here knows. I have a dedicated server and hosting 2 word press websites off it. its an ubuntu server and im using Apache. I have a feeling that my server might be compromised. For some reason one of my word press sites sometimes says that there are a lot of people connected to it (100-300). The thing is that there is not sign of any activity on the website. I have a chat set up for it and even guess that visit automatically get added to the chat as a guest user. but there is never anyone there. I have some security plugins for the word press sites and I get a lot of strange activity. Random IP trying to load pages that don't exist, people trying to log in as admin, ext... this is happening non stop.

Basicaly I want to make shure that my server is safe and that is it now being used for bad things without me knowing. Im farely knew to php and Im not expert on an ubuntu server. Can someone please tell me were I should go from here. I guess just point me in the right direction for me to figure out what to do about this.

Thanks

Comment: [server fault](https://serverfault.com/) is predestined for all your server-questions.... but you should rather just ask a search engine. try, for example: "check if wordpress is compromised", you'll get **many** helpful resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a list of things I do to secure my server.

1. Turn on UFW (sudo ufw enable) and then only allow ports that are
   actually used. (sudo ufw allow 80)
2. Make sure MySQL only allows connections from localhost  Enable TLS
   on mail services. Even if it's a self signed cert. You don't want
   passwords sent in the clear.
3. Install ssh bruteforce blockers like denyhosts or fail2ban. (sudo
   apt-get install denyhosts) Look into making ssh key-based logins
   only. Learn AppArmor. If you use fairly vanilla configurations, then
   it's extremely easy. Just make sure it's turned on. It will help
   reduce zero-day exploits.
4. Depending on physical access to the server, you may even want to
   look at encrypting the data on the harddisk.  Follow other
   recommendations in this link.

   EDIT: I forgot to edit this when I didn't have enough reputation to add more links. The link meant here is the last link below. Never trust your users. If you are having multiple users with access to the system, lock them down. If you have to give them sudo access, give them only what they need. Use common sense. Think real hard about how you'd get in if you were ever locked out. Then close those holes. A few more things to consider. Most people forget about physical access. All the software configurations in the world don't mean anything if I can physically walk in with a LiveCD and steal your data. Beware of social engineering. Ask questions to verify who is on the phone and make sure they have authorization to make the request they are making.

[Source Where I have found these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146775/what-can-be-done-to-secure-ubuntu-server)
Since I'm still a 'new' user, I can't post more than 2 links. You can read up more about this subject here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html and pay special attention to https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/security.html

Comment: to UFW: make sure you allow SSH *before* enabling it, or you might shut yourself out of your server.

Comment: thanks. I already have UFW enabled, and im pritty shure i have fail2ban. Also ssh is the only way to log in. the websites are not exacly public, as in i dont advertise it and it is more of a learning experience for my self and im the only one with access. Ill look into apparmor. as for someone getting phisical access to it, i see it highly unlikely. It being hosted by a branch of OVH server provider. Its my first time im trying to do website hosting on a server from scratch and I was just a bit concerned about the traffic. btw the website is olympusknights.com